# How to make a dock like plank

Tags: ubuntu-dock

I want to make a dock like plank but haven’t found anything in the Internet on how to do that.Does anyone know how?

Comment: Are you looking for software recommendations or do you have a specific question/problem regarding software development?

Comment: Well no questions just want to know if there are any tools I should use.Or what language I should use to write it.

Comment: Your question is really too broad for this format. I would suggest using your favorite search engine.  You can possibly look for beginner projects that help you write a simple program and go from there.

Comment: Please contribute to existing docks instead of reinventing the wheel. *Fragmentation is Why Linux Hasn’t Succeeded on Desktop: Linus Torvalds* https://itsfoss.com/desktop-linux-torvalds/

Comment: What's a plank?

Comment: @Levente A dock https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/12/a-guide-to-using-plank-dock-on-linux.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an easy question. Plank is FOSS, Free and Open Source Software. It means that the source code for it is available for inspection and reuse to anyone.

Download and study the code. It will learn you how one can create a dock. Feel free to reuse parts of the code for your own doc. You are free to do so, provided you maintain the credit to the original code in your source code.

It is also possible to collaborate with the Plank project. Then you become a contributor that can add the features you want.

Comment: Thank you I am new to linux so I do not know much